# How to open modal window using angular4 and load component content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I have imported `ngbModal` module fron ng2bootstrap now i am trying to open modal window and load the current component content into modal body. what is the correct approach to implement ?

search.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Pipe, PipeTransform, EventEmitter,Input, Output,OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {GtConfig} from '@angular-generic-table/core';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-detail',
      templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css'],

    })
export class DetailComponent implements OnChanges{
    constructor(private detailService: DetailService,private ngbModal: NgbModal) {};
    ngOnInit(){
     this.secondConfigObject = {
         settings: this.getBaseSettings(),
         fields: this.getBaseFields(),
         data: []
         };
    })
    }

     rowData(event) {
      console.log('Event',event);
      this.detailService.changeChart(event);
    }
   execModal(evt){
     const modalReg  = this.ngbModal.open(Component);
   }
}
```

Comment: use ng-bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: yes thats what i am using for modal window `ngb`

Comment: scroll down the docs a little...here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview